# Community like features in bug tracking software?

Tags: bug-tracking

Does anyone know of a bug tracking piece of software that has community based features like rep, friends, badges and community based voting?

I'm looking for a hybrid of uservoice, stackoverflow and bugzilla. Does such a beast exist?

Comment: Maybe you should petition to Jeff and Joel to combine their Stack Overflow with their FogBugz! :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A commercial offering is [Get Satisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/home/companies) which offers a similar service. Their main selling point is to encourage your users to help other users, with the ability for your staff to intervene and help. It also integrates with your web application.

See the "what it is" page - I would post a link but it redirects you if you follow a link from here.

> > > Part feedback system, part community engine, completely different than anything you've had a chance to test with your customers.
> > >       14,000 companies. Thousands of employees participating in conversations. Millions of users. What gives?